# Mongod aborts on Mac

Tags: mongodb

When I try to start mongod on my Mac I get the following error in the log file:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.041+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.044+03:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.044+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.045+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":30381,"port":27017,"dbPath":"yourfolder","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Chaims-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.045+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.045+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"18.2.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.045+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"yourfolder"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"myfile.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.047+03:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.047+03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T16:29:32.047+03:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: File permission error, or another mongod already running? `"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}`

Answer (score 18):

Please use one of the following solutions.

### for Linux

```
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
$ sudo service mongod start
```

### for Mac

```
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
$ sudo brew services restart mongod
```

Comment: what for windows?

Comment: can you tell what to do for windows?

Comment: While running the restart cmd, I got the following error

Tapped 1 command (40 files, 425.4KB).
Error: No available formula with the name "mongod".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

```
sudo mongod
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30700824)